# How are nVidia Cards configured to run on Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

It's been a while since I've dealt with video cards.. I have a new MSi 6QF Leopard Pro which came with a NVidia GTX960M graphics card. However, when I'm working on my laptop, I often see messages about how my "Intel HD Graphics 530 has stopped responding but has restarted." My question is, why is the Intel HD Graphics 530 even being used? Shouldn't my display be running with the GTX960 or is that only during video games and 3D rendering? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean how are they configured to run on Windows 10.  Nvidia updated the drivers to support the version of the WDDM which is supported by Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Intel CPUs now come with integrated graphics on the chip.  Here is a [FAQ](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005718.html) from Intel about integrated graphics.

Windows 10 *should* know when to switch between integrated and discrete graphics.  However, it does not always perform this properly.

When an application launches which requires the additional power of the NVIDIA graphics card, systems with NVIDIA Optimus technology seamlessly switch over to that, then turn it off when no longer required.

Note: Use of the dedicated NVIDIA graphics over the integrated Intel graphics can reduce battery life.

The switching to the NVIDIA graphics depends on application profiles. If an application has no such profile, you can assign the graphics card manually:

You can manually set the graphics preferences by:

- Double-click NVIDIA Control Panel.
- Click View and next Add "Run with graphics processor" Option to Context Menu.     - Close the NVIDIA Control Panel.
- Right-click the application title and select Run with graphics processor.
- Then, click High-performance NVIDIA processor.

Make sure you have the latest drivers for your hardware.  To get the *latest* driver for your NVidia GPU, you can find this in the NVidia Control Panel.  As for the Intel graphics, I find the easiest method is the [Intel Driver Utility](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html).

Answer (score 1):

NVidia's driver installation includes the 'Optimus' software which manages the workload between your discrete NVidia card and the integrated Intel Graphics.

See this [link](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus) for details.

On a side note you might want to try updating your [intel graphics driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/88345/Intel-HD-Graphics-530-for-6th-Generation-Intel-Core-Processors) if you are getting that error often.